# what kind metadata can be stored in a ssl certificate?

Tags: ssl, certificate, authorization

I want to use certificates for MTLS. I am thinking about ways to not only authenticate but also authorize the clients.

As it stands, a cert is primarily to authenticate. So one option would have some kind of database with a mapping of role to certificate.

I am wondering if it's possible to store such metadata directly inside the certificate. Similar to the way tokens might work, where they carry their own claims.

I think if it's possible, it has the benefit of the backend being stateless other than having to know the CA that signed the client cert. The downside of it may be that once a cert has certain roles, they cannot be changed any more.

But, right now, I just want to know. What kind of metadata can be stored in a cert. I know of things like Subject name and country. Is it possible to define arbitrary fields?

Comment: Most of the meta data is used to validate the certificate is valid or not valid and/or current or expired/revoked.

Comment: see here for some related discussion. Certs are about identity, and I generally agree with the advice against mixing Authentication functionality using that Identity with Authorization functionality. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19776/adding-custom-data-in-x-509-certificate also, not being able to manage authorization choices without revoking the cert seems like a huge design flaw.

Comment: For prior art, search about "attribute certificates" (and why they didn't succeed), SPKI, compare with JWT tokens...